# What does the anonymous function passed into the off function mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, events, handler

What does the anonymous function passed into the **off** function mean?

For instance, what does the following mean:

`$jqueryEl.off("click", function() { console.log("When will it be called?"); });`.

Will the `function() { console.log("When will it be called?");` be called once all the click listeners are removed or will it be called instead of the removed click listeners?

I am asking this since there is no clear answer to this in [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/off/):

> A handler function previously attached for the event(s), or the special value false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does the anonymous function passed into the off function mean?

Nothing useful.

Since it is a function expression, it will generate a **new** function. Therefore it **can't** have been *previously attached for the event*.

It also isn't `false`.

Whoever wrote that code made an error.

---

Typically this happens when someone intended to conditionally remove the function:

```
const myHandler = function() { console.log("When will it be called?"); };

$jqueryEl.on("click", myHandler);

$somethingElse.on("click", function () {
    $jqueryEl.off("click", myHandler);
});
```

… but when they have created two identical functions, instead of reusing the same function for the two different calls.